# object has no attribute 'tk' - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

in the following code is an issue, which I can't find.
The Error:

> AttributeError: 'game' object has no attribute 'tk'

I guess it's because the field-function.
The functions, which are important for my program are shown in the following code.

```
import tkinter as tkinter
from tkinter import *

# class for the game 
class game(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        # main-window 
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        # title 
        self.root.title("TicTacToe")
        # text member
        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set(" ")
        # config
        self.root.geometry("178x130")
        self.root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.root['bg'] = '#1c6796'
        self.root.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))
        # buttons 
        self.singleplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Singleplayer", command = self.singleplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.multiplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Multiplayer", command = self.multiplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.quit_button = Button(self.root, text = "Quit", command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.singleplayer_button.place(x = 48, y = 10)
        self.multiplayer_button.place(x = 51, y = 50)
        self.quit_button.place(x = 70, y = 90)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def field(self):

        # 9 buttons for the field
        self.field1 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field2 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field3 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field4 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field5 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field6 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field7 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field8 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field9 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.back   = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'back', command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')

        # display buttons
        self.field1.place(x = 50, y = 10)
        self.field2.place(x = 100, y = 10)
        self.field3.place(x = 150, y =10)
        self.field4.place(x = 50, y = 60)
        self.field5.place(x = 100, y = 60)
        self.field6.place(x = 150, y = 60)
        self.field7.place(x = 50, y = 120)
        self.field8.place(x = 100, y = 120)
        self.field9.place(x = 150, y = 120)
        self.back.place  (x = 50, y = 180)
        self.reset.place (x = 150, y = 180)

    def singleplayer_window(self):
        self.sw = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.sw.title("Singleplayer")

        # config
        self.sw.geometry("240x210")
        self.sw.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.sw.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))

        # draw the field
        self.field()

        self.sw.mainloop()
```

I hope you can help me!

PS: I let out the Multiplayer-function, because it's similar to the singleplayer-funtion.

btw: It was the first time I really worked with classes, so please don't blame me!

Comment: use `super().__init__(self.root)` after `self.root = tkinter.Tk()` also remove the `self.sw.mainloop()`. I think it would be better if you place the `root=Tk()` outside the `game` class  and place it under `if __name__=='__main__'` or some main function from where you can pass the root to the game class constructor. (don't  forget to call super it should look something like this `super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialise `tkinter.Frame` using `super().__init__(self.root)`
Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tkinter
from tkinter import *

# class for the game 
class Game(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        # main-window 
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        # title 
        self.root.title("TicTacToe")
        # text member
        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set(" ")
        # config
        self.root.geometry("178x130")
        self.root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.root['bg'] = '#1c6796'
        self.root.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))
        # buttons 
        self.singleplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Singleplayer", command = self.singleplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.multiplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Multiplayer", command = self.multiplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.quit_button = Button(self.root, text = "Quit", command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.singleplayer_button.place(x = 48, y = 10)
        self.multiplayer_button.place(x = 51, y = 50)
        self.quit_button.place(x = 70, y = 90)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def field(self):
        # 9 buttons for the field
        self.field1 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field2 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field3 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field4 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field5 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field6 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field7 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field8 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field9 = tkinter.Button(self, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.back   = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'back', command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')

        # display buttons
        self.field1.place(x = 50, y = 10)
        self.field2.place(x = 100, y = 10)
        self.field3.place(x = 150, y =10)
        self.field4.place(x = 50, y = 60)
        self.field5.place(x = 100, y = 60)
        self.field6.place(x = 150, y = 60)
        self.field7.place(x = 50, y = 120)
        self.field8.place(x = 100, y = 120)
        self.field9.place(x = 150, y = 120)
        self.back.place  (x = 50, y = 180)
        self.reset.place (x = 150, y = 180)

    def singleplayer_window(self):
        self.sw = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.sw.title("Singleplayer")

        super().__init__(self.sw) # Initialise the frame
        super().pack() # `pack`/`grid`/`place` the frame

        # config
        self.sw.geometry("240x210")
        self.sw.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.sw.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))

        # draw the field
        self.field()

        self.sw.mainloop()

app = Game()
```

That will cause problems if you call `singleplayer_window` multiple times as @ BryanOakley said. That is why I think you shouldn't inherit from `tkinter.Frame` so:

```py
import tkinter as tkinter
from tkinter import *

# class for the game 
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # main-window 
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        # title 
        self.root.title("TicTacToe")
        # text member
        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set(" ")
        # config
        self.root.geometry("178x130")
        self.root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.root['bg'] = '#1c6796'
        self.root.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))
        # buttons 
        self.singleplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Singleplayer", command = self.singleplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.multiplayer_button = Button(self.root, text = "Multiplayer", command = self.multiplayer_window, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.quit_button = Button(self.root, text = "Quit", command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')
        self.singleplayer_button.place(x = 48, y = 10)
        self.multiplayer_button.place(x = 51, y = 50)
        self.quit_button.place(x = 70, y = 90)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def field(self):
        # 9 buttons for the field
        self.field1 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field2 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field3 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field4 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field5 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field6 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field7 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field8 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.field9 = tkinter.Button(self.frame, textvariable=self.text, command = self.move, height = 2, width = 4)
        self.back   = tkinter.Button(self.frame, text = 'back', command = quit, font = 'Times 10 italic')

        # display buttons
        self.field1.place(x = 50, y = 10)
        self.field2.place(x = 100, y = 10)
        self.field3.place(x = 150, y =10)
        self.field4.place(x = 50, y = 60)
        self.field5.place(x = 100, y = 60)
        self.field6.place(x = 150, y = 60)
        self.field7.place(x = 50, y = 120)
        self.field8.place(x = 100, y = 120)
        self.field9.place(x = 150, y = 120)
        self.back.place  (x = 50, y = 180)
        self.reset.place (x = 150, y = 180)

    def singleplayer_window(self):
        self.sw = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.sw.title("Singleplayer")

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.sw) # Initialise the frame
        self.frame.pack() # `pack`/`grid`/`place` the frame

        # config
        self.sw.geometry("240x210")
        self.sw.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.sw.iconphoto(True, tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\nicod\Desktop\TicTacToe\icon.png'))

        # draw the field
        self.field()

        self.sw.mainloop()

app = Game()
```

Comment: This is a very odd solution. You should be calling `super().__init__` once for an object and typically in the `__init__` of the class, but this solution will call it every time the single player button is clicked.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know but I think that the frame is used to create the actual playing field which is after the main root is hidden. I will still edit my answer. Thanks for the catch. Is that better?

Comment: Thank you alot! I dont know what this super().__init__ is, but it works! :D

Answer (score -2):

You should add `self.tk = some_value` in your class, because there is really no attribute `tk`. Or maybe you meant `self.root`

Comment: This is wrong. The problem is that OP never calls `super().__init__()`. The error is called by the `... = tkinter.Button(self, ...)`. In that case `self` isn't a tkinter widget/window